# Cannot find the directory src/main/java/com/example/demo of Spring package

Tags: java, spring

Thank you for your help so far. I'm following https://spring.io/quickstart but I found I cannot find the directory src/main/java/com/example/demo.

[Spring step2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAWzC.jpg)

I only have folders D:\Downloads\Honda\src\main\java

[My folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGbbG.jpg)

After I explored it, I got this result.

[explore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjsi8.jpg)

Comment: Do you miss to fill up the package name ?

Comment: Thank you, but what do you mean? :D

Comment: can you please click the button explore before downloading the project ? and tell me what is the result

Comment: What IDE are you using? What dir is the root of your project, I'm assuming D:\Downloads\Honda ? How are you compiling and running your code? Are you using either Maven or Gradle to manage dependencies / set project structure / build your code?

Comment: @HadesZazif Thank you, I've edited my result into my article. :D

Comment: @Kevin Hooke I haven't used my Visual Studio Code to edit it. My root is D:\Downloads\Honda. :D

Comment: What plugin are you using in VSC to compile your code? Is the project opened as a Java Project?

Comment: You said 'haven't used my VSC' but if you are using VSC and this was a typo I think the answers to your questions are probably covered in this guide https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-tutorial